# how to modify this erd diagram?

Tags: sql, database, diagram, erd

I'm sorry i couldn't form the question to be clear enough to describe the problem but I'm not a pro at this.
I'd like to ask

-how should I make this  ERD format in the correct way ?
scenario is the salesman chooses an expert depending on what the expert days are and months will be available on + the kind of job like :part-time or full time ?
any ideas to modify the erd diagram ? maybe a new entity relationship ? i'm not sure 
**problem is underlined in the first picture please check it out**>>
[how can i solve this erd diagram , check this picture of erd diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzsZ5.jpg)

[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOMtG.png)

Comment: For starters, things like email and birthdate are attributes of the expert, not related entities, so they should be inside the box of the expert. You might want to google "how to create and erd". Here's one link that might help: http://holowczak.com/drawing-e-r-diagrams-with-crows-foot-notation-using-microsoft-visio-tutorial/4/

Comment: Thanks but they are already attributes not entities as shown in the first picture.
please help :(

Comment: You seriously asking us for help with your homework?

Comment: i dont know how to classify this to search for the problem + this is a real application on the design phase :) . please help